# Session is not coming inside single sign on session Tomcat

Tags: session, tomcat, single-sign-on

I am using Single sign on (SSO) for my applications. I have extended the SSO of tomcat valve and adding the following method to get the SSO session id.

```
 public String getSSOId(String sessionId){
    SessionAttrManager.log("getSSOID " +sessionId);
    Set<Session> keySet = reverse.keySet();
    String SSOId = "";
    Iterator<Session> iterator = keySet.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Session session = iterator.next();
    SessionAttrManager.log("getSSOID "+session.getId());
        if(session.getId().equals(sessionId)){
            SSOId = reverse.get(session)!=null?(String)reverse.get(session):null;

 }
   }
    return SSOId;
}
```

And every application has form based authentication. There is one application for which the SSO is coming as null, the reverse map does not have the session for the application. but I am able to login to it once I have done the authentication.

Any possible reason, why a session id will not come inside a SSO session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the problem. Actually, if we don't give any page in  in web.xml, that page bypasses the SSO session. The second scenario where i found the same issue was, if the url-pattern is not as per the specification or an invalid url pattern, that will also be ignored by SSO session.